# Sqoop-2 fails on large import to single node with custom query using sqoop shell

Tags: hadoop, jdbc, hdfs, sqoop

I am prototyping migration of a large record set generated by a computationally expensive custom query. This query takes approximately 1-2 hours to return a result set in SQL Developer

I am attempting to pass this query to a simple `Sqoop` job with links `JDBC` to `HDFS`

I have encountered the following errors in my logs:

> 2016-02-12 10:15:50,690 ERROR mr.SqoopOutputFormatLoadExecutor [org.apache.sqoop.job.mr.SqoopOutputFormatLoadExecutor$ConsumerThread.run(SqoopOutputFormatLoadExecutor.java:257)] Error while loading data out of MR job.
>   org.apache.sqoop.common.SqoopException: GENERIC_HDFS_CONNECTOR_0005:Error occurs during loader run
>       at org.apache.sqoop.connector.hdfs.HdfsLoader.load(HdfsLoader.java:110)
>       at org.apache.sqoop.connector.hdfs.HdfsLoader.load(HdfsLoader.java:41)
>       at org.apache.sqoop.job.mr.SqoopOutputFormatLoadExecutor$ConsumerThread.run(SqoopOutputFormatLoadExecutor.java:250)
>       at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>   Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.LeaseExpiredException): No lease on /user/username/schema/recordset/.72dee005-3f75-4a95-bbc0-30c6b565d193/f5aeeecc-097e-49ab-99cc-b5032ae18a84.txt (inode 16415): File does not exist. [Lease.  Holder: DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_-1820866823_31, pendingcreates: 1]

When I try to check the resulting `.txt` files in my `hdfs`, they are empty.

Has anyone encountered and solved this? Also, I am noticing additional bugginess with the `Sqoop shell`. For example, I am unable to check the job status as it always returns UNKNOWN.

I am using `sqoop-1.99.6-bin-hadoop200` with `Hadoop 2.7.2 (Homebrew install)`. I am querying a remote `Oracle 11` database with the `Generic JDBC Connector`.

**I have already conducted a smaller import job using the `schema/table` parameters in `create job`**

I am tempted to migrate the entire schema table by table, then just use Hive to generate and store the record set I want. Would this be a better/easier solution?

Comment: For most people, "Sqoop" means the initial, battle-tested utility a.k.a. "Sqoop 1" (current version is 1.4.6) -- and I'm not sure how many people would trust their production system on "Sqoop 2" a.k.a. "someday we will fill the feature gap and fix the issues and actually reach the 2.0 mark and then deprecate V1, just give us another couple of years".

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter Thanks for the suggestion. I changed the question to reflect that its Sqoop2. Should I regress to 1.4.6? Will it work with my Hadoop install?

Comment: Actually I'm not sure it would make a difference, it's the 1 hour latency that's killing you.

Comment: Sqoop1 is just like Pig, it's a fat client that uses the core Hadoop services (HDFS + YARN + optionally Hive MetaStore) but evolves at its own pace; by the way, I would be surprised if it was not bundled in your distro by default.

Answer (score 1):

> org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.LeaseExpiredException
>
> This query takes approximately 1-2 hours to return a result set in SQL
>   Developer

I would bet that Sqoop 1.99 creates an empty HDFS file *(i.e. the NameNode gets the request, creates the file but does not materialize it for other clients yet, grants an exclusive write lease for Sqoop, and assigns responsibility for writing block#1 to a random DataNode)* then waits for the JDBC ResultSet to produce some data... without doing any keep-alive in the meantime.

But alas, **after 60 minutes**, the NameNode just sees that the lease has expired without any sign of the Sqoop client being alive, so it closes the file -- or rather, makes as if it was never created (no flush has ever occured).

Any chance you can reduce the time lapse with a `/*+ FIRST_ROWS */` hint on Oracle side?

Comment: If you are open to an Oracle-centric solution, you could try to bribe an Oracle DBA to set up a DataPump file export that you can trigger with an `EXEC`, plus some kind of file transfer from the Oracle box to HDFS *(using the WebHDFS REST interface for instance)*. Could be more efficient and reliable, on the whole. But it involves the Oracle people in dev and ops.

Comment: Caveat - AFAIK WebHDFS does *no* integrity check of any kind, so you'd better use it only with compressed files (CRC32 = poor man's integrity check).

Comment: Unfortunately, I have little control over the Oracle server. However, this seems like a valid solution when there is control over the full stack.